# Как пересчитать данные в js при снятии галочки на чекбоксе?

Tags: javascript

Конструкция такая, ставлю галочку, выводится скрытый блок, также берется из value цена 600, правда далее я ее в скрытый инпут передаю, чтобы в бд отправить, ну и из скрытого инпута беру для умножения, в скрытом блоке селект, в этом селекте я выбираю кол-во номеров, эти номера я беру и умножаю на эту полученную сумму и вывожу результат, так же я в див по id, вывожу и кол-во и стоимость 600.

Помимо этого у меня есть еще сумма и кол-во, это я тоже беру из инпутов и умножаю, далее первый результат и второй я складываю и вывожу в конечную сумму и вывожу конечный результат.

Как мне при снятии галочки с чекбокса делать перерасчет?
Я сделал обнуление, чтобы в результатах по 0 показывало, но оно не пересчитывает, а тупо обнуляет, как бы заглушка что есть 0.

В общем, когда я снимаю галочку, после того как ее поставил и выбрал там что-то и происходил подсчет и плюсование сумм и т.д, когда я снял галочку, конечный результат вывода суммы не пересчитывается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#priceKonder').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        const priceKonder = $("#priceKonder").val(); // берем значение из валуе из чекбокса, сумма 600
        $('#konderPr').val(priceKonder); //если галочка стоит выводим значение
        $('#blockNomerKonder').show(100); // показываем блок
      } else {
// ПРИ СКРЫТИИ БЛОКА
        $('#konderPr').val(0); //выводим 0 если галочка не стоит
        $('#blockNomerKonder').hide(100); // скрываем блок
        $('#price').text('0'); // Обнуляем показываемую цену
          $('#konderKolvo').text('0'); // Обнуляем количество
        $('#sum').text('0'); //Обнуляем показываемую суму
        $('#nomerKonder').val(0); // Меняем значение селекта на 0 "Выбрать"
      }
    });
  });

  function calc() {
  
  //добавил для эксперемента еще данные для подсчета
  const price = $('#price').val(); //берем цену
  const kolvoNomerBezkondeya = $('#kolvoNomerBezkondeya').val(); //берем кол-во
  //-------------

    const konderPr = $("#konderPr").val().replace(/\./, '') //берем цену за кондер из скрытого импута
    const nomerKonder = $('#nomerKonder').val().match(/\d*/)[0] //берем значение с селекта, кол-во номеров выбрали 1, 2 и т.д
    let priceKolvo = (+price * +kolvoNomerBezkondeya); 
    let rezultKonder = (+konderPr * +nomerKonder);
    let rezultall = (rezultKonder + priceKolvo).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1.');

    $('#price').html(konderPr); //выводим прайс 600
    $('#konderKolvo').html(nomerKonder); // выводим кол-во
    $('#sum').html(rezultKonder); //выводим результат
    $('#sumall').html(rezultall); //выводим конечный результат всего
  }

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  //запускаем весь скрипт при запуски страницы
  $(document).ready(function() {
  calc();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ac-custom">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="priceKonder" id="priceKonder" value="600" />
    <label for="priceKonder"><span>Номер с кондиционером, +<strong>600</strong> рублей к стоимости номера.</span></label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" id="konderPr" name="konderPr" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="konderPr" name="konderPr" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" id="kolvoNomerBezkondeya" name="kolvoNomerBezkondeya" value="1">

<div id="blockNomerKonder" style="display:none">
    <label>Номера с кондиционером <b>*</b></label>
    <select name="nomerKonder" id="nomerKonder" class="js-select2">
      <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1 номер (с кондиционером)">1 номер (с кондиционером)</option>
      <option value="2 номера (с кондиционером)">2 номера (с кондиционером)</option>
      <option value="3 номера (с кондиционером)">3 номера (с кондиционером)</option>
    </select>
</div>


<br /><br />

Стоимость номера:<div id="price"></div><br />
Количество:<div id="konderKolvo"></div><br />
Результат:<div id="sum"></div><br />
Конечный результат за все:<div id="sumall"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли сделать, делюсь решением.
Надо было просто добавить calc(); строка 16

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#priceKonder').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        const priceKonder = $("#priceKonder").val(); // берем значение из валуе из чекбокса, сумма 600
        $('#konderPr').val(priceKonder); //если галочка стоит выводим значение
        $('#blockNomerKonder').show(100); // показываем блок
      } else {
// ПРИ СКРЫТИИ БЛОКА
        $('#konderPr').val(0); //выводим 0 если галочка не стоит
        $('#blockNomerKonder').hide(100); // скрываем блок
        $('#price').text('0'); // Обнуляем показываемую цену
          $('#konderKolvo').text('0'); // Обнуляем количество
        $('#sum').text('0'); //Обнуляем показываемую суму
        $('#nomerKonder').val(0); // Меняем значение селекта на 0 "Выбрать"
      }
      calc(); // <<<< THIS
    });
  });

  function calc() {
  
  //добавил для эксперемента еще данные для подсчета
  const price = $('#price').val(); //берем цену
  const kolvoNomerBezkondeya = $('#kolvoNomerBezkondeya').val(); //берем кол-во
  //-------------

    const konderPr = $("#konderPr").val().replace(/\./, '') //берем цену за кондер из скрытого импута
    const nomerKonder = $('#nomerKonder').val().match(/\d*/)[0] //берем значение с селекта, кол-во номеров выбрали 1, 2 и т.д
    let priceKolvo = (+price * +kolvoNomerBezkondeya); 
    let rezultKonder = (+konderPr * +nomerKonder);
    let rezultall = (rezultKonder + priceKolvo).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1.');

    $('#price').html(konderPr); //выводим прайс 600
    $('#konderKolvo').html(nomerKonder); // выводим кол-во
    $('#sum').html(rezultKonder); //выводим результат
    $('#sumall').html(rezultall); //выводим конечный результат всего
  }

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  //запускаем весь скрипт при запуски страницы
  $(document).ready(function() {
  calc();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ac-custom">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="priceKonder" id="priceKonder" value="600" />
    <label for="priceKonder"><span>Номер с кондиционером, +<strong>600</strong> рублей к стоимости номера.</span></label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" id="konderPr" name="konderPr" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="konderPr" name="konderPr" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" id="kolvoNomerBezkondeya" name="kolvoNomerBezkondeya" value="1">

<div id="blockNomerKonder" style="display:none">
    <label>Номера с кондиционером <b>*</b></label>
    <select name="nomerKonder" id="nomerKonder" class="js-select2">
      <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1 номер (с кондиционером)">1 номер (с кондиционером)</option>
      <option value="2 номера (с кондиционером)">2 номера (с кондиционером)</option>
      <option value="3 номера (с кондиционером)">3 номера (с кондиционером)</option>
    </select>
</div>


<br /><br />

Стоимость номера:<div id="price"></div><br />
Количество:<div id="konderKolvo"></div><br />
Результат:<div id="sum"></div><br />
Конечный результат за все:<div id="sumall"></div>
```